# Finding the amount of SOL deactivated from staking with a validator

Tags: rpc, stake

We're a validator operator. Delegations come and go and when a delegator deactivates their stake with us we'd like to know the amount of SOL that came back into their stake account. It seems there must be some RPC calls that'll give us this.

The stake deactivation transaction does not contain any amount, just the relevant addresses. The `postBalance` of that transaction is also not the amount that was un-staked because it includes any other balance on the stake account or the rent exempt reserve, for example.

I'm aware I can call the `getProgramAccounts` RPC method with the address of the stake program, an offset of 124 bytes and the address of the stake account in question. But this only works for the currently active stakes (and maybe those that have just deactivated) but NOT for the stake accounts that have both deactivated and then re-staked with another validator. The data returned is based on the current state of the stake program, not the historical state, AFAICT.

There must be a way to get this data because Solana Compass (a validator explorer) has it on their "epoch history" table for a given validator.

[This answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4140/2510) (to a closely related question also from me) is helpful but points out that the approach described doesn't give you the history.

There's got to be a way, right?